# Spotify album embed does not work, not clickable

Tags: wordpress, embed, spotify

I'm trying to embed spotify album on wordpress based website. It is working well on backend while editing page and for new articles but not at home page: http://goo.gl/984skV

Web dev tools shows this error:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "http://www.******.com" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "https://embed.spotify.com".  The frame requesting access has a
>   protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of
>   "https". Protocols must match.

Any tips?

Comment: Fix the protocol to match? `The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.`

Comment: @dingo_d I have tried with http and https and even just using //. None of these work on homepage but when i added embed code to new article ( http://goo.gl/9j2viF ) it works just fine.